# qt thread options

Tags: qt, qthread

I'm currently writing a programme which has a function to hash a number of files in the background. I've read the Qt4 documentation a number of times over and I still can't really figure out which threading option is best for this.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html

There's really no need to update the GUI when it's done with each file, I just don't wish to block the GUI and I really only need a single signal/slot connection upon completion. I'm thinking of extending QThread for a hashing thread. Does this sound reasonable/right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have [this article](http://codethis.wordpress.com/2011/04/) bookmarked as it nicely illustrates the use of QThread and highlights some common misconceptions about it. Sample code available, which runs without blocking the GUI. Sample is hosted on RapidShare, but they seem to have implemented some sort of timed waiting period since I last used it.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a good place to use the QtConcurrent::map() function. The map function can apply the same operation to a container of objects, in your case, files. Once you start the map function, you can create a QFutureWatcher and connect to its finished signal to be notified when all of the work is done.